# Python - Remove dictionary from list if key is equal to value

Tags: python, dictionary

How do I remove from list a all dictionaries which link value is included in list b?

```
a = [{'link':'http://example.com/1/', 'id': 1}, {'link':'http://example.com/2/', 'id': 2}]
b = ['http://example.com/2/', 'http://example.com/3/']
```

a should be:

```
a = [{'link':'http://example.com/1/', 'id': 1}]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
a = [x for x in a if x['link'] not in b]
```

Demo:

```
>>> a = [{'link':'http://example.com/1/', 'id': 1}, {'link':'http://example.com/2/', 'id': 2}]
>>> b = ['http://example.com/2/', 'http://example.com/3/']
>>> a = [x for x in a if x['link'] not in b]
>>> a
[{'link': 'http://example.com/1/', 'id': 1}]
```